# ngFor does not display for values for custom iterator

Tags: angular

I have created a custom class Matrix that implements Iterable<T[]>.  I have tested it and it works in Jasmine.

When I place the Matrix into ngFor loop.  It seems to fire, but nothing is displayed to screen

I have placed a stripped down version here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-itmpcy?file=src/app/app.module.ts

I am expecting 5 div tags containing `[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Hey @key as i have check stackblitz demo and update that code please do that way.

Replace your `ngFor` with this `*ngFor="let myRow of displayMatrix['matrix'];let i = index;"`

Comment: shouldn't the matrix property be unavailable because it is private?

Comment: Please check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dhrftb?file=src/app/app.component.ts